# Add each blocks date value as a class

Tags: jquery, each

Hello I would like to grab each date value just as string and add it as a class to article $('.alle-feesten'), what it does now is adding all values to every block so every block gets 3 extra classes. Every block should only get it's date so block1 gets value1, ... Thanks in advance

```
  $('.alle-feesten').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(zonderSlash($('.feest-datum').text()));
  });

  function zonderSlash(datum) {
    datum_string = datum.split('/');
    new_date = datum_string[0] + datum_string[1] + datum_string[2]
    return new_date;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `.feest-datum` is an ancestor of `.alle-feesten` you probably want to do this.

```
$('.alle-feesten').each(function(i) {
    var self = $(this);
    self.addClass(zonderSlash(self.find('.feest-datum').text()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
 var aux = 0;
 $('.alle-feesten').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(zonderSlash($('.feest-datum').text()), aux); 
    aux++;
  });

  function zonderSlash(datum, i) {
    datum_string = datum.split('/');
    new_date = datum_string[i];
    return new_date;
  }
```